Why can I initialize a Map with an iterable literal but not a variable of an iterable?
I can initialize a new Map() with a literal iterable (array of tuples) without a problem:
const tmp = new Map([
  [1, true],
  [2, false]
])

But if I try to initialize the Map with an iterable array:
const d = [
  [1, true],
  [2, false]
]
const tmp = new Map(d)

I receive error: (I'm not understanding the error)

TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload  1  of  4 ,
(iterable?: Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>): Map<unknown,
unknown> , gave the following error. Argument of type  (number |
boolean)[][]  is not assignable to parameter of type
Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>  The types returned by
Symbol.iterator.next(...)  are incompatible between these types.
Type  IteratorResult<(number | boolean)[], any>  is not assignable to
type IteratorResult<readonly [unknown, unknown], any> Type
IteratorYieldResult<(number | boolean)[]>  is not assignable to type
IteratorResult<readonly [unknown, unknown], any> Type
IteratorYieldResult<(number | boolean)[]>  is not assignable to type
IteratorYieldResult<readonly [unknown, unknown]> Type  (number |
boolean)[]  is not assignable to type  readonly [unknown, unknown] 
Target requires  2  element(s) but source may have fewer.


MapConstructor requires readonly array of readonly tuples of size 2.
interface MapConstructor {
    new(): Map<any, any>;
    new<K, V>(entries?: readonly (readonly [K, V])[] | null): Map<K, V>;
    readonly prototype: Map<any, any>;
}

If you assign an array to a temporary variable, it is inferred to be mutable array of arrays:

size of each inner array is not constrained to 2
Types at each position are not constrained

const d = [
  [1, true],
  [2, false]
];
// const d: (number | boolean)[][]

You can use as const assertion to force it to be readonly tuple of readonly tuples:
const d = [
  [1, true],
  [2, false]
] as const;
// const d: readonly [readonly [1, true], readonly [2, false]]
const tmp = new Map(d);


No, readonly is not the reason - the problem is that it's an array not a tuple.

@Lesiak - Great, thank you for the help. I would have thought the use of const (rather than let) would have establish immutability?

@Bergi good point, updated the answer.

@NV_steve const variable means it cannot be re-assigned to point to another object. It does not affect the type of object the variable points to.

OK, understood. I appreciate the input and help from both of you.
